# How to prevent overflow of inner content of parent component?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm designing a component for my social media app. This component will allow the user to share their goal with friends. The design looks fine on wide screens, but on smaller screens the design looks as pictured below.

[image]

I originally thought the fix for this would be override the typography to use responsive typography instead, but this has not resolved the issue.

I'm thinking the way to fix would be to have the parent container grow to contain the typography that fills it. How would I accomplish this using Material UI? The code sandbox for my project is found here: https://codesandbox.io/s/goal-post-design-yvvjp

The code for the component is listed below:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import {
  Container,
  Typography,
  Paper,
  makeStyles,
  Avatar,
  Grid
} from "@material-ui/core";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  paper: {
    height: "15vh"
  }
}));

export default function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Container>
      <Paper>
        <Grid
          className={classes.paper}
          container
          direction="row"
          alignItems="center"
        >
          <Grid
            item
            container
            direction="column"
            justify="center"
            alignItems="center"
            xs={3}
          >
            <Avatar />
            <Typography variant="subtitle2">Benjamin world</Typography>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={9}>
            <Typography variant="body1">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur
              quam lorem, malesuada sed sapien non.
            </Typography>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Paper>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use either:

```
paper: {
  height: "15vh",
  overflow:"auto"
}
```

[image]

or

```
paper: {
  height: "15vh",
  overflow:"hidden"
}
```

[image]

**make the paper component height grow based on how much content is within:**

```
paper: {
      height: "auto"
}
```

**Before :**

> Desktop version

[image]

> iPhone 5/SE

[image]

**After :**

> Desktop version

[image]

> iPhone 5/SE

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to make the paper component height grow based on how much content is within?

Comment: @Benjamin-wofford you can just simply use height:auto

Answer (score 1):

If stacking is what you want, I've changed the styles so it won't have a fixed height and added padding

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  paper: {
    padding: "15px"
  }
}));
```

Then added `sm` to the grid

```js
<Grid
  item
  container
  direction="column"
  justify="center"
  alignItems="center"
  xs={12}
  sm={3}
>
  <Avatar />
  <Typography variant="subtitle2">Benjamin world</Typography>
</Grid>
<Grid item xs={12} sm={9}>
  <Typography variant="body1">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur
    quam lorem, malesuada sed sapien non.
  </Typography>
</Grid>
```

Comment: This answer is an improvement for most smaller devices, but the content still flows past the Paper component when viewing on an iPhone 5/SE

Comment: @Benjamin-wofford Seems like bits gone missing before I posted the answer. Have a look now, I've edited the answer.